# Read status from failed Relax NG validation in HXT

Tags: haskell, relaxng, hxt

Validating an XML file in Haskell works fine with *HXT* and *Relax NG*, apart from one thing: how can I get the result?

With the following code, the XML file `xmlFilename` gets validated against the Relax NG scheme `rngFilename`. In case of an error, an error is output to `stderr`, and the evaluation continues.

```
v <- runX
    ( readDocument
        [ withRemoveWS yes   -- remove redundant whitespace
        , withValidate no    -- don't validate source by DTD
        ] xmlFilename
      >>>
      -- validate source by Relax NG
      validateDocumentWithRelaxSchema [] rngFilename
    )
```

In case of an error, the variable `v` holds the following information according to [the hxt-relaxng documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt-relaxng/latest/doc/html/Text-XML-HXT-RelaxNG-Validator.html#v%3avalidateDocumentWithRelaxSchema):

> in case of validation errors, an empty document with status information in the root [is output]

The resulting tree with a faulty document really holds a `status` (and `module`) attribute:

```
NTree (XAttr "module") [NTree (XText "validate document with Relax NG schema") []],
NTree (XAttr "status") [NTree (XText "2") []]
```

Now the questions:

**How can I check the output of `validateDocumentWithRelaxSchema` whether there was a validation error?**

**Is there a predefined function I can use for that (but haven't found yet)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself:

HXT error handling is located in [Text.XML.HXT.Arrow.XmlState.ErrorHandling](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.1.1/doc/html/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlState-ErrorHandling.html) with the interesting function `getErrStatus`.

```
v <- runX
    ( readDocument
        [ withRemoveWS yes   -- remove redundant whitespace
        , withValidate no    -- don't validate source by DTD
        ] xmlFilename
      >>>
      -- validate source by Relax NG
      validateDocumentWithRelaxSchema [] rngFilename
      >>>
      getErrStatus
    )

case v of
    --severity [0]=[c_ok]
    [0] -> --continue processing

    --severity: [1]=[c_warn], [2]=[c_err], [3]=[c_fatal], else=something_really_really_bad_happened
    _ -> --do error handling
```

Comment: That way, all error messages are output to `stderr`. That could be avoided by using `errorMsgCollect` and afterwards `getErrorMessages`, but I'm not sure how to return both arrows (the result of `getErrorMessages` and of `getErrStatus`).